# Paypal payflow integration

Tags: python, paypal, python-requests

I keep running into the following issue:

When I make the following python-requests:

```
data = [
  ('PARTNER', 'PayPal'),
  ('VENDOR', 'my vendor id'),
  ('USER', 'my user id went here'),
  ('PWD', 'my password'),
  ('TRXTYPE', 'S'),
  ('AMT', '40'),
  ('CREATESECURETOKEN', 'Y'),
  ('SECURETOKENID', '12528208de1413abc3d60c86cb15'),
]
data = urllib.urlencode(data)

response = requests.post('https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com', data=data, verify=False, headers=headers)
print response.text
```

This gives me following error:

```
RESULT=1&RESPMSG=User authentication failed&SECURETOKENID=12528208de1413abc3d60c86cb15
```

I made sure my vendor/user id were correct; I'm using my admin credentials; I use to logon to paypal manager; so I'm trying to keep up with the following doc: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

Comment: can you get it using `curl` like in example in your link ?

Comment: you don't have to use `urlencode` - `requests` will do it automatically if you use dictionary with `data=`

Answer (score 1):

The format of your request looks correct. 
Since you are receiving User Authentication Failed, you are touching the Payflow Server.

There are many reasons that you may be getting User Authentication Failed.
One is incorrect credentials. Keep in mind that the parameters are case sensitive. You can always change the password for the user. Also make certain that the user has the Role of API_FULL_TRANSACTIONS assigned.

If you are certain that your credentials are correct, and the user has enough permissions to perform API calls, another possibility that could be causing this issue is an IP address block in your PayPal Manager Account.

Below is a help article about different reasons for receiving User Authentication Failed:

https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/why-did-i-get-the-error-%22user-authentication-failed%22-or-%22merchant-identification-error%22-ts1223/1

You can verify if there is a block on IP addresses in PayPal Manager.

1. Log into PayPal Manager
2. Click on Account Administration
3. Under Manage Security Click on Allowed IP Addresses (For API Transaction Processing)

If there are any IP addresses listed that means you have blocked all IP addresses except for the ones that are listed in your PayPal Manager Account.

You can either add the IP address from your server or remove the IP addresses that are listed.

Thank you, 
Jennifer